# Use apply to retrieve a list of vectors of dates in R

Tags: r, date, apply

I have a dataframe `df` with 2 columns and 10k rows:

```
df <- 
structure(list(date1 = c("2015-09-29", "2018-07-24", "2021-07-20", 
"2016-12-19"), date2 = c("2015-11-26", "2018-09-26", "2021-09-21", 
"2017-03-17")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 4L))
```

| date1 | date2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2015-09-29 | 2015-11-26 |
| 2018-07-24 | 2018-09-26 |
| 2021-07-20 | 2021-09-21 |
| 2016-12-19 | 2017-03-17 |

I have a way to retrieve the dates between date1 and date2, using a loop:

```
library(lubridate)

p <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  p[[i]] <- seq(floor_date(df$date1[i], "months"), 
                      floor_date(df$date2[i], "months"), 
                      by = "months") %m+% months(1) - days(1)
}
```

so this list has as many elements as rows has the data frame, and each element has a vector (might have different lengths) with the dates between (the dates between are the last day of the month).

The point is, I'm trying to make this efficient, now it takes around 1 min, and I know apply (and the other functions of its family) are more efficient than a loop, but it's not working.

How could I implement this?

Comment: I strongly suspect the answer might be "don't do that", but it's hard to be confident without knowing the follow-up workflow from here.  One approach that might be worth considering would be to generate a named vector of days between the earliest `date1` and the latest `date2` so you only need to generate it once, then use the other dates to subset that vector.

Comment: You might get a reasonable speed-up by specifying the size of your list in advance of your loop rather than iteratively growing your list (which is one of the tricks the `apply` family uses). Try specifying `p <- vector(mode = 'list', nrow(df))` instead of `p <- list()`

Comment: I'm having trouble replicating from your code.  I think you're missing a `)` in the `for( i in...` line.  Can you also please include an example of the desired output (what would the four vectors be from your example table?)

Comment: I have a function `time_seq_v()` from my package `timeplyr` which is pretty efficient.
`timeplyr::time_seq_v(floor_date(df$date1, "months"), 
           floor_date(df$date2, "months"), by = "month") %m+% 
  months(1) - days(1)`

It's vectorised over start and end dates.

Source: github.com/NicChr/timeplyr

Comment: `mapply()` or `purrr::pmap()` could also work e.g. `mapply(seq, df[["date1"]], df[["date2"]], MoreArgs = list(by = "month"))` or `purrr::pmap(df, function(date1, date2) seq(from = date1, to = date2, by = "month"))`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
df[] <- lapply(df, lubridate::floor_date, "months")
Map(seq.Date, df$date1, df$date2, "months")
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "2015-09-01" "2015-10-01" "2015-11-01"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "2018-07-01" "2018-08-01" "2018-09-01"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "2021-07-01" "2021-08-01" "2021-09-01"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "2016-12-01" "2017-01-01" "2017-02-01" "2017-03-01"
```

Answer (score 0):

If execution time is important try **data.table**

```
library(data.table)

do.call(c,           # get a vector instead of a data.table element per entry
  split(data.table(  # construct the monthly date
    d1 = as.Date(paste0(sub("-\\d{2}$", "", df$date1), "-01")), 
    d2 = as.Date(paste0(sub("-\\d{2}$", "", df$date2), "-01")))[, 
      .(Dates = seq.Date(d1, d2, "month")), by=1:nrow(df)],
  by="nrow", keep.by=F))
$`1.Dates`
[1] "2015-09-01" "2015-10-01" "2015-11-01"

$`2.Dates`
[1] "2018-07-01" "2018-08-01" "2018-09-01"

$`3.Dates`
[1] "2021-07-01" "2021-08-01" "2021-09-01"

$`4.Dates`
[1] "2016-12-01" "2017-01-01" "2017-02-01" "2017-03-01"
```